# como crear un query en eloquent para mostrar una tabla con fechas en laravel?

Tags: laravel, sql, eloquent

Lo que quiero hacer es una tabla como esta que esta pintada en excel con una consulta en eloquent de laravel lo que pasa es que ya intente con varios codigos sin tener exito el unico que funciona es el que pongo en el post pero solo para el editor sql en mi caso lo tengo en xampp

esta es la base de datos que estoy usando https://mega.nz/#F!BjQUQSwT!xkpe22-9QanpYP5VCQ0b2w

[image: images of my database and the table i want to show in laravel eloquent]

este es el codigo que me ha funcionado pero solo como consulta en la terminal de xampp pero no me fuciona en eloquent laravel me sale error al querer pintarlos en la ventana html por medio de un foreach

```
   public function __construct(){


}
public function index(Request $request){
    if ($request){
        $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));

        $material=DB::select(db::raw("SELECT vtm.fecha  fecha,
 (SELECT SUM(vtm2.cantidadMaterial) FROM vehiculo_transporte_material vtm2
  WHERE vtm.fecha=vtm2.fecha AND vtm2.idMaterial=1) AS arena,
  (SELECT SUM(vtm2.cantidadMaterial) FROM vehiculo_transporte_material vtm2
  WHERE vtm.fecha=vtm2.fecha AND vtm2.idMaterial=2) AS base,
  (SELECT SUM(vtm2.cantidadMaterial) FROM vehiculo_transporte_material vtm2
   WHERE vtm.fecha=vtm2.fecha AND vtm2.idMaterial=3) AS Subbase,
   (SELECT SUM(vtm2.cantidadMaterial) FROM vehiculo_transporte_material vtm2
   WHERE vtm.fecha=vtm2.fecha AND vtm2.idMaterial=4) AS filtrante,
   FROM vehiculo_transporte_material  as vtm
   GROUP BY vtm.fecha"));

   return view('traza.materiales.indexProduccion',
   ["material"=>$material,"searchText"=>$query]);

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. La pregunta debe estar en español. 2. Muéstranos lo que has intentado.

Comment: disculpa pense que era la version ingles